# Magento: Registration - let store owner confirm account

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm tweaking a magento store for a wholesale company. Because this is a wholesale company, we only want to allow companies, not privates/individuals, to create a new account. We want to do that by letting the store owner check the VAT number (which is a required field in the registration form) of the company, **then let him set the account to 'confirmed'.**

The preferred way is to have a confirmation e-mail sent to the store owner (and a different notification mail to the customer saying that the confirmation is pending). However, letting the store owner set the customer's account to 'confirmed' in the admin panel is fine too.

So, my problem is this. For as far as I can find, it's only possible to choose whether you want to send a confirmation link before 'activating' the account or not, but this confirmation link will always get sent to the customer. It seems to me you can't change this in the Admin panel, but how can I change this in the code? Any tips, code snippets, or even telling me what file I would have to change, would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free extension by Vinai Kopp (who works for Magento), that should fit your needs: **Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation**

- [Extension on Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-activation.html)
- [Source on Github](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation)

It's a small, clean extension that does not use core rewrites and can be easily deactivated or uninstalled. So there should not be any compatibility issues.

Comment: It provided the solution for me, yay!